# Power supply for speakers

Tags: power-supply, audio, speakers

I have two big speakers with only bare wires for input and a small alarm clock with a low voltage output. I was wondering how I would supply more power to the speakers (there are two of them)? I was hoping to gain the extra power supply from mains power( 240v in New Zealand). P.s yes I am only a hobbieist so please explain it like I'm stupid :)

Comment: This is a question about hooking up consumer equipment, not electronic design.

Comment: You need a "power amplifier" - finding and connecting one is off topic, though if you build one, and run into a specific problem, solving it may be on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, just providing an extra power supply, from mains or otherwise, will not allow the clock to drive the external speakers.

Here is a broad explanation of what needs to be done to arrive at a workable solution:

1. Determine if the alarm clock output is an actual audio signal, or (usually) a DC voltage that drives a piezoelectric buzzer.
2. If it is an audio signal, determine the AC component of the drive voltage of the sound output.
3. Determine the impedance (Ohms) of the external speakers you have, and the supported power (Watts) of each speaker.
4. Design or buy a power audio amplifier that is matched to the speaker impedance, to optimally drive speakers of that impedance, to the desired power level, as determined above. The amplifier should also accept an input signal of the voltage level the alarm clock's audio output provides.
5. Use the alarm clock audio output signal to feed the power amplifier signal input, and the power amplifier output to the speaker.

If, however, the question is essentially seeking some off-the-shelf product that does this job, this may not be a good site for the question.